# Buscar en mysqli con un campo separado por coma

Tags: mysqli

Me gustaría hacer una búsqueda en mysql usando una variable que contiene datos separados por ,. Hasta ahora siempre he hecho esto con un loop, pero lo mismo hay alguna forma de buscar directamente usando esa variable.

La idea seria buscar todas las id que tiene almacenadas la base de datos que estén en ese listado.

No tengo absolutamente nada de codigo para poner una parte.

ejemplo de estructura de datos:

```
id = int autoincrement
concepto = varchar
precio = int
```

y llamemos a la variable `$idaconsultar` y de contenido tiene `"1,5,8,14"`

La búsqueda que quisiera hacer es: consultar los datos que coinciden con los id que hay en la variable `$idaconsultar`, sin tener que hacer un `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias probar con algo como:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,concepto,precio FROM TuTabla where id in (?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $idaconsultar);
```

Esto te crearia una query a la cual le asignarias como parámetro ese String donde aparecen las ids que quieres buscar y la consulta te devolvería los registros en los que estuvieran esos ids.

Version sin parametros:

```
SELECT id,concepto,precio FROM TuTabla where id in ("1,5,8,14");
```

Comment: Genial, es justo lo que necesitaba :) mil gracias